# How to check if copy_if returned true for any in the range with ostream_iterator?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

I want to be able to check the result of `std::copy_if()` to see if anything was printed to `std::cout`.

For example:

```
vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

struct is_odd {
    bool operator()(int val)
    return val % 2 == 1;
};

copy_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ostream_iterator<int>{cout},
        is_odd());
```

Is there a way to check if anything was printed? I tried looking at the return result of `std::copy_if()`, but it doesn't seem helpful. Maybe I should be using a different algorithm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged C++11 so... it seems to me a work for a lambda function where an external variable (`someOut` in the following example) can record if a value is left out

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main ()
 {
   bool someOut { false };

   std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

   std::copy_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout},
                [&](int val) { bool ret { val % 2 == 1 };
                               if ( ! ret ) someOut = true;
                               return ret; });

   std::cout << std::endl << someOut << std::endl;
 }
```

If you want to count the number of the values left out, you can substitute `someOut` with an `std::size_t countOut { 0U }` variable and increment it (`if ( ! ret ) ++countOut;`) in the case.

Answer (score 0):

A silly non-built-in way is to wrap `is_odd` in your own function that will update a global variable if it ever returned `true`.

Comment: yeah, it seems like its either this, or use a temporary data structure to keep count.

Comment: This is generally considered dangerous, since something like is_odd should not have side-effects. Imagine someone else discovers the function is_odd and want to use it in some other part of the code.

Comment: What I did instead was make the bool part of the function object, and made the declaration of the function object inside the only function that uses it. That should take care of that problem. I'll take a look the other option you presented. Thanks

Comment: @Dillydill123 notice that copy_if takes predicate by copy, not by reference. Make sure that it can deal with this (simplest way is to use a lambda, capturing something by reference)

Comment: You just saved me from a disgusting bug. Nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

This is familiar to: 
[How to return value of std::copy in case of success or failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681702/how-to-return-value-of-stdcopy-in-case-of-success-or-failure).

You could write your own output iterator that wraps `ostream_iterator` to count how many values have been written.